# transformar strings numéricos a floats o integer usando jupyter

Tags: string, pandas, jupyter, float, integer

tengo un archivo CSV que he creado de tabla excel que contiene 3 columnas como estas:

```
0  Peso  Talla  IMC
1  65,1  1,65   25,1
2  70,4  1,55   30
```

como pueden notar, el archivo de origen tiene "comas" y al cargar el CSV, jupyter los reconoce como strings:

```
peso={["65,1"; "70.4"]}
```

y asi con 500 datos aprox

no he podido encontrar una manera de trasformar los datos a integer o floats para poder trabajar con ellos como "numeros" y ya lo intente con:

```
df["IMC"]=df["IMC"].map(int)
df["IMC"].unique() #para ver si persiste el problema
```

pero arroja este error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-5928a427302c> in <module>
----> 1 df["IMC"]=df["IMC"].map(int)
  2 df["IMC"].unique()
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
3380         """
3381         new_values = super(Series, self)._map_values(
-> 3382             arg, na_action=na_action)
3383         return self._constructor(new_values,
3384                                  index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
1216 
1217         # mapper is a function
-> 1218         new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
1219 
1220         return new_values
pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' 34.78   '
```

alguna sugerencia ?

Answer (score 2):

Estabas muy cerca a la respuesta, pero tienes dos errores.

1. Aunque para los humanos la **coma** y el **punto** si pueden indicar flotantes, para el interprete de python, no lo son.

   ```
    # reemplazamos las comas con puntos en las columnas
    df["IMC"] = df["IMC"].str.replace(',','.')
   ```
2. En este punto la columna aun se considera de tipo **string** por lo que debes convertirla a numérica. Además no puedes convertir un "string que representa un flotante" a un tipo "int"

   ```
    # 1ra forma, (recomendada) pandas hace todo el trabajo
    df['IMC'] = pd.to_numeric(df['IMC'])

    # 2da forma, mapeas toda la columna a tipo float
    df['IMC'] = df['IMC'].map(float)

    # 3ra forma
    df['IMC'] = df['IMC'].astype(float)
   ```

Si luego necesitas de tipo `int` ahora si lo puedes castear cuando ya son `float`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
import csv

with open('archivo.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    header = next(reader)
    rows = [header] + [[row[0], int(row[1])] for row in reader]

for row in rows:
    print row
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, ahora me arroja este error: "Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)"

Comment: Creo que lo podrías hacer más fácil con ```re.sub```pasándole el patrón por ejemplo ```@. *``` para que te elimine todo lo que está después del carácter de arroba. Investiga acerca de eso